# Touch down on UITapGestureRecogniser

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Is it possible to setup UITapGestureRecogniser for touch down event? Default is touch up...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that's not possible, but it shouldn't be hard to subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` to create your own recognizer that does that.

You could also use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with the `minimumPressDuration` property set to `0.0`. Note however that your action will then be called continuously when the touch moves, so make sure to check that the `state` of the recognizer is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` in the action (this will only be once).

Answer (score 3):

A tap gesture recogniser detects a tap. This is different from touch up.

The best way to detect a touch down is to write your own touchesBegan method in the custom UIView or UIViewController.